# DRF post to a field without showing it in the API form

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework API. I want to have a field 'result' that is on the model, but not shown on the API form, yet still appears in the json when I list the data or view the detail.

So I want to see this on my POST form:

[image: POST]

And this on my GET request:

[image]

How can this be done?

serialisers.py:

from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Expression

class ExpressionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.operator_mapping = {
        "add": " + ",
        "minus": " - ",
        "divide": " / ",
        "multiply": " * "
    }
    super(ExpressionSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    model = Expression
    fields = ["expression", "result"]

def create(self, validated_data):

    expression_obj = Expression.objects.create(**validated_data)

    return expression_obj

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.expression = validated_data.get('expression', instance.expression)
    instance.result = validated_data.get('result', instance.result)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

views.py:

```
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from lxml import etree

from .serialisers import ExpressionSerializer
from .models import Expression


class ExpressionAPIView(APIView):

    def __init__(self):
        self.operator_mapping = {
            "add": " + ",
            "minus": " - ",
            "divide": " / ",
            "multiply": " * "
        }
        self.queryset = Expression.objects.all()
        self.serializer_class = ExpressionSerializer


    def get(self, request):
        return Response({'data': request.data})

    def post(self, request):
        root = etree.XML(request.data['expression'])

        result = self.evaluate_expression(root)[0]

        exp_parsed = self.expression_to_string(root) + f" = {result}"

        serializer_data = {'expression': exp_parsed, 'result': result}

        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            data=serializer_data,
        )

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


    def expression_to_string(self, root):
        expression = ""

        for child in root:
            if child.tag != "root" and child.tag != "expression":
                if child.tag == "number":
                    num = int(child.text)
                    if child != root[-1]:
                        expression += f"{num} {self.operator_mapping[root.tag]} "
                    else:
                        expression += f"{num}"

                else:
                    if child != root[-1]:
                        expression += f"({self.expression_to_string(child)}) {self.operator_mapping[root.tag]} "
                    else:
                        expression += f"({self.expression_to_string(child)})"
            else:
                expression += f"{self.expression_to_string(child)}"

        return expression

    def evaluate_expression(self, root):
        numbers = []
        for child in root:
            if child.tag == "number":
                num = int(child.text)
                numbers.append(num)

            elif child.tag in ["add", "minus", "divide", "multiply"]:
                _ = self.evaluate_expression(child)

                def eval_sublist(_, operator):
                    x = _[0]
                    for i in range(1, len(_)):
                        x_str = f"{x}{operator}{_[i]}"
                        x = eval(x_str)
                    return x

                numbers.append(eval_sublist(_, self.operator_mapping[child.tag]))

            else:
                numbers.extend(self.evaluate_expression(child))

        return numbers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the [`result` field as being `read only` on your serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields).

That can be achieved through either defining the extra serializer parameters `read_only_fields` inside the `Meta` class or by explicitly defining the `result` field and adding a `read_only=True` flag to it.

Comment: I tried this! I have a function that updates result based on the expression field. If I set result to read only it never updates!

Comment: can you share the relevant code? the serializer field being read only shouldn't influence in your model being saved (unless you're actively trying to save the result through the serializer)

Comment: so yeah, by making it `read only`, the field data won't appear in `validated_data` - you can try a hacky approach where you access the information through `self.initial_data`, what, while not the best of approaches, isn't as unsafe since you're the one creating the data that actually is reaching the serializer.